# Need a little help with Metasploit and Java?

Tags: java, metasploit

I'm a junior programmer and i was asked in my job to test java using metasploit... I followed this detailed environment: https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2012/08/27/lets-start-the-week-with-a-new-java-0day
But when i searched for tutorials i didn't understand them... Can you help me?

Thanks,
Matias

Comment: We can help you understand them, sure. But you have to *ask a question*. “Help me” is not a question, and we can't help you because we don't know what your difficulty is. Tell us what you read, how far you understood, and what is blocking you.